# ImportError: cannot import name 'int_classes' from 'torch._six' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_six.py)

Tags: pytorch

I am working on healthcare image dataset for image segmentation. More specific, it is "**Spinal Cord Gray Matter Segmentation Using PyTorch**". When I am trying to install libraries initially using this code:

!pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.4.0-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl

!pip3 install torchvision

!pip install medicaltorch

!pip3 install numpy==1.14.1

it is showing some errors in between required satisfied like this:

[1st screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p89UG.png)

[2nd screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1shT.png)

After that I am importing libraries:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import time
import os

import numpy as np

from tqdm import tqdm

from medicaltorch import datasets as mt_datasets
from medicaltorch import models as mt_models
from medicaltorch import transforms as mt_transforms
from medicaltorch import losses as mt_losses
from medicaltorch import metrics as mt_metrics
from medicaltorch import filters as mt_filters

import torch
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torch import autograd, optim
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import torch.nn as nn

import torchvision.utils as vutils

cudnn.benchmark = True
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

This importing is throwing an error like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-80b8c583d1fe> in <module>()
     20 
     21 
---> 22 from medicaltorch import datasets as mt_datasets
     23 from medicaltorch import models as mt_models
     24 from medicaltorch import transforms as mt_transforms

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/medicaltorch/datasets.py in <module>()
     11 from torch.utils.data import Dataset
     12 import torch
---> 13 from torch._six import string_classes, int_classes
     14 
     15 from PIL import Image

ImportError: cannot import name 'int_classes' from 'torch._six' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/_six.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

can someone help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In pytorch 1.9 `int_classes` variable in `torch._six` was removed. [facebookresearch/TimeSformer#47](https://github.com/facebookresearch/TimeSformer/pull/47)
Use this code instead.

```
from torch._six import string_classes
int_classes = (bool, int)
```

See source here: https://github.com/visionml/pytracking/issues/272